# Multiple Nodes graph to single node graph in python

Tags: python, recursion, data-structures, depth-first-search

I have a Directed Acyclic graph, something like this:

```
[a, b, c] --> [p, q] --> [p, a, c] --> [x, y, z]
```

Here, each of the alphabets is a node.
From the above graph, I want the list of all the graphs having single nodes.
eg
One graph can be: `a --> p --> a --> y`
Another can be: `b --> p --> p --> z` etc.

I can do a depth-first  search (`DFS`) on the main graph to traverse it, but I'm not sure how to do multiple `DFS` to extract every graph having single character

Comment: Can you share any code example you did to try it, so we can try to take a look what might have gone wrong?

Comment: It is not acyclic...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a list of the node sets you can do something like this -

```
from itertools import product
s =[[1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7]]
list(product(*s))
```

output -

> [(1, 3, 6), (1, 3, 7), (1, 4, 6), (1, 4, 7), (1, 5, 6), (1, 5, 7), (2,
>   3, 6), (2, 3, 7), (2, 4, 6), (2, 4, 7), (2, 5, 6), (2, 5, 7)]